# Is there any way to read/write 9-data bit, 2-stop bit and 1- parity bit UART message from/to MCF52235 ColdFire microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, uart, coldfire

I want to communicate between MCF52235 ColdFire microcontroller and a specific unit which has following  message specifications
9-data bits
2- stop bits
one parity bit

However, the MCF52235 ColdFire microcontroller data sheet says it supports 
"Data format can be 5,6, 7 or 8 bits with even, odd or no parity". 
I wonder is there any tricky way to address this issue.

Thanks

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/411386/seeking-9-bit-serial-port-card-for-windows-pc/411438#411438  But since you specify 9 bits of data *plus* a parity bit, then there is no software workaround.  You would have to use a UART that is 9-bit capable, e.g.  16950 or 16C950.

Comment: Thanks Sawdust for your response. I just wanna check is there any kludges way to address this issue by accessing lower layer behaviors.

Comment: *"I just wanna check is there any kludges"* -- Reread what I wrote.  No workaround means no kludges.  BTW literate people do not write *"I wanna"* unless you want to sound infantile.